# Is it possible to loop changing opacity values in HTML5 or css?

Tags: javascript, css, html

This is the code I'm currently working with.  It works to my purposes of layering the two images.  What I am trying to do is have the layer0 opacity lower to 0 as the layer1 opacity increases to 100 over a few seconds. {and then on to layer1 with layer2 and so on eventually looping back to layer0}

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<head>
  <style>
    div.layer0
    {
      width: 371px;
      height: 345px;
      background:url(image2.jpg);
      opacity:1;
      filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }

    div.layer1
    {
      width: 371px;
      height: 345px;
      background:url(image3.jpg);
      opacity:0;
      filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="layer0">
    <div class="layer1">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: not easily.

You're probably better off with javascript for the looping. You could make a delayed keyframe animation, but that won't allow you to loop from the start again: jsfiddle.net/G4PTM (firefox/ie10) -- You could make a lot of keyframes with different timings and you can make it work, but it would require quite a bit of code and not scale well (say you wanted to add another layer/image the code would quickly become unmanagable)

With some javascript, you can just loop through the divs and add and remove a classname to trigger the transitions, like Jon mentioned. Here is a working demo (using jQuery for simplicity, let me know if you need vanilla js)

#### html

```
<div class="layer0">
</div>
<div class="layer1">
</div>
<div class="layer2">
</div>
```

#### css

```
div {
    width: 371px;
    height: 345px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
div.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
div.layer0 {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/373/345);
}
div.layer1 {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/372/345);
}
div.layer2 {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/374/345);
}
```

#### js+jquery

```
var firstDiv = $(".layer0");
var current;

function loopsie() {
    // if first iteration or reached end, use first div
    if (!current || !current.length) current = firstDiv;
    current.addClass("active");

    setTimeout(function() {
        current.removeClass("active");

        setTimeout(function() {
            current = current.next();
            loopsie(); // recurse
        }, 2000);

    }, 2000);
}

//initialize
loopsie();
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/G4PTM/2/

---

Plain JavaScript (Without jQuery):

```
var firstDiv = document.querySelector(".layer0"); // IE 8+
var current;

function loopsie() {
    // if first iteration, use first div
    if (!current) current = firstDiv;
    current.classList.add("active"); // IE 10+, shim at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

    setTimeout(function() {
        current.classList.remove("active");
        // account for text node (if there is whitespace in html)
        if (current.nextSibling && current.nextSibling.nodeName == "DIV") {
            current = current.nextSibling;
        } else if (current.nextSibling && current.nextSibling.nextSibling && current.nextSibling.nextSibling.nodeName == "DIV") {
            current = current.nextSibling.nextSibling;
        } else {
            // reached end
            current = firstDiv;
        }
        loopsie(); // recurse
    }, 2000);

}

//initialize
loopsie();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G4PTM/6/

Comment: That is much closer to what i need to figure out, thank you!  Instead of fading to white, I'm trying to fade out to the next image fading in.  I'm not sure if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Eyefoundart You can just skip one of the `setTimeout`s to make the fade in start the same time as the previous fades out: http://jsfiddle.net/G4PTM/3/

Comment: The  jsfiddle.net/G4PTM/3 was perfect thanks :)  The vanilla js would be rockstar, but I'm sure I'll get it worked out either way :D

Comment: @Eyefoundart Added a non-jquery version for you ;)

Answer (score 3):

To continually do this in a loop, you'll need some javascript to add an appropriate `active` class to the image you want displayed. Then using CSS transitions you can achieve the fading between images that you require.

I created a jsfiddle to give you an example of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/pacso/H6dqq/

The basics are as follows.

Some simple HTML divs which you'll be fading:

```
<div class='red square active'></div>
<div class='yellow square'></div>
<div class='green square'></div>
<div class='blue square'></div>
```

These are just going to be coloured squares, but yours could contain images.

Next, some CSS markup:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.square {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari */
}
.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Note that my transition will alter the opacity of the div itself. You may need to change this as needed.

Now the javascript to make it work on an endless loop:

```
jQuery(function() {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        activeSquare = $('.active');
        nextSquare = activeSquare.next()
        if (nextSquare.length == 0) {
          nextSquare = activeSquare.siblings().first();
        }
        nextSquare.addClass('active');
        activeSquare.removeClass('active');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Fairly straightforward. Click the [link to my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pacso/H6dqq/) and hit the run button if you want to see a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transitions. The example below fades .layer0 in and out in a timespan of 500 ms:

```
div.layer0 {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
    transition:opacity 500ms ease-out;
}

div.layer0:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: animations or transitions? because animations would work peachy keen too.

Comment: The transition property in `div.layer0:hover` is not necessary.

Comment: How does this loop through divs?

Comment: transitions really.  basically what i want to do is start with the original photo, fade from variation to variation of it and then fade back to the beginning image and repeat.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I don't think it is possible to loop through divs with CSS only. You would have to use jQuery...